# Wordpress plugin creating sidebar on the theme/page

Tags: php, plugins

I am creating a plugin and I need it to create a sidebar on the page, but I have no idea what to do or what to search. So once my plugin is activated, the sidebar needs to appear. The color and text are set by the user in plugin settings. I have already done that and now I need that sidebar to appear once I activate it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sidebars are theme-territory, imho. You might want to consider registering widgets instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a widget in your plugin. Once you have the widget, just drag and drop it into the side bar. This might help.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-a-wordpress-widget/